# How to solve for $L$ in $X = LL^T$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I know I'm not the first to do this and I can't find what it's called that would tell me how to solve for $L$ when $X$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite. I know

```
orth(A)*transpose(orth(A)) = [Identity matrix]
```

and

```
[q,r]=qr(A)
q*r == A
```

but I can't find $X = LL^T$. If anyone knows what the method is named/called that I could use to solve this it'd be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for *Cholesky Factorization*.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! One thing I was wondering though is is it possible to do this for a positive semidefinite matrix? I believe Cholesky factorization only works on positive definite unless I'm misunderstanding something.